# getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(NAME) return null if the NAME doesn't equal "Scores"

Tags: android, android-intent, null

I have really really strange problem. 
Activity4:

```
 protected void ToActivity5() {
    Index = 0;
    index = 0;

    ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    for(int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        scores.add(i, Integer.toString((int) (score[i] * 100.0)) + "%");
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity4.this, Activity5.class);
    b.putStringArrayList("Score", scores);

    b.putBoolean("Second", second);

    if(!second) {
        for(int i = 0; i < tpairs.size(); i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < tpairs.get(i).size(); j++)
                pairs.add(tpairs.get(i).get(j));
        b.putParcelableArrayList("TPairs", pairs);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        score[i] = 0.0;

    //if(second)
        //finish();
    second = true;

    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Activity5:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_5);
    setTitle(R.string.title_5);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> percents = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Score");

    ArrayList<TwoStrings> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < percents.size(); i++)
        arrayList.add(i, new TwoStrings(getResources().getTextArray(R.array.StatisticDays)[i].toString(), percents.get(i)));

        //tpairs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("TPairs");
        //tpairs.size();
        //ArrayList<String> ssd = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Scores");

    lv5_1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv5_1);

    TwoStringsAdapter adapter = new TwoStringsAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_5_1, arrayList);
    lv5_1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And the problem is that when I put something with "Score" name then I can get it in the next activity but if the name is different e.g. "Second" or whatever then I can't get the object in Activity5 (I get null object). Please help me. Unfortunately I haven't found any similar problem. That's why I write about the problem here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Score");`

Comment: Ok, i will try it.

Comment: It still doesn't work.. This is what I get in logcat - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference. It is because I call percents.size() and the percents object is null.

Comment: Ok, i've found the source of problem. It is caused by this - b.putParcelableArrayList("TPairs", pairs);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
 Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<String> percents = intent.getStringArrayList("Score");
```